# What is the difference between 'prepare for the party' and 'prepare the party'?

Tags: prepositions, difference

There are two sentences:

1. I prepare the party for him.
2. I prepare for the party for him.

What is the difference between the two sentences in meaning?

Comment: "**I prepare for the party for him**" is incorrect English.

Comment: Notice that you are using *Present Simple*, which means that you either do it **habitually** or you should've used *Present Continuous* instead.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Prepare** - *is used to talk about something prepared for others to benefit from*
2. **Prepare for** - *is used to talk about somebody who will benefit from something prepared*

"*Prepare for the party*" means that you didn't prepare the party (somebody else did) and you will benefit from that. "*Prepare the party*" means that you are the one who is preparing a party others will benefit from.

Example:

- I am preparing an exam. *(I am the one who is creating the exam for others to pass)*
- I am preparing for an exam. *(Someone has created an exam that I need to pass)*

Answer (score 0):

To prepare is to make preparations or make, **prepare for** is **to make ready for something that has not yet occurred**.

Although you can say to  prepare a party for someone, normally, one would say: to organize  party for someone.

Here is an illustration of prepare for.

"I prepared **for** the exam by studying hard". [to make ready for something that will happen to me].

"**I prepared for** the party for him". [to get ready for the party that was being given for him. get ready as in get dressed, for example, or set the table and make the food].

"I prepared a meal for him"=I made him a meal.

**Now, it is possible to imagine the use of the simple present as  historical narrative**:
One might be describing a number of past events, including:
[On Sunday], I prepare for the party for  him by having my hair done and buying a new dress. I order the food and set the table.

So, it can be used as historical present. Narrative present but not in conversation where the simple present is only a habitual action.